# What Actually "Force Stop" mean in Android?

Tags: android, service

I've a question relating to `Android Life Cycle`.
I'm working on an app with a `Foreground Service` (notification in Status Bar). After starting the service, I see `Application Manager` in the phone the app has "Force Stop" button Enabled. Then I Stops the service by code

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShakeService.class));
```

and I found that even after service is stopped(notification also gone), "Force Stop" button is Enabled. And am sure No-other service or `AsyncTask` or `Handler` is there in the app.
 Do you have any ideas What exactly "Force Stop" mean & how to stop the service Perfectly (so the Force Stop button remain disabled)??
Thanks

Comment: You can probably get your answer in this link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-does-the-force-stop-button-mean

Comment: In general way to find your answer try this... http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m8/471413-force-stop.html

Comment: I think this is what you need to know, see this link: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/97257.aspx

Comment: thanks guys, but I had gone through all these links. Please have a look at my clarification & query to @sasikumar below.

Answer (score 0):

The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus.

- If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's
  less likely to be killed,
- if the service is declared to run in the foreground  then it will almost never be killed.
- if the service was started and is long-running, then the system will
  lower its position in the list of background tasks over time.

  [more details refer Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

if you manually do force stop means its killed all the services in that application.

Comment: If I Stop the service by code(stopService()), It should be seen in the "Application Manager" i.e., the "Force Stop" button should be disabled because I myself Freed-Up the Resources. Am I wrong??

Comment: yes if the services is stopped means button  disabled ..because no services is runing in app..button enabled when service started,,,got it?

Comment: I Got It. But my query remains the same. When I stopped the service with stopService() and then looks in the Application Manager the Force Stop button is still Enabled (means the user can Stop it by pressing it). "Force Stop" button should be disabled.

Comment: did you use onDestroy() method in service class

Answer (score 0):

Applications exited by user may have services and listeners registered to device events. These will work according to events received by application even if user quits the app.

For example GCM will still work even if application is exited by user.

Where as if `Force Stop` is clicked manually by user , then neither any `Services`/`Listeners`/`Background` Operations will be running for that particular application.

If `Clear Cache` or clicked by user, this will clear off data stored by application for temporary purpose than databases like `SqLite` or `Realm`. For example data stored in `SharedPreference`